# validating email addresses in AWS athena query using SQL functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Looking for example of regex etc. of how I can determine when an email address is not in a valid format.  I've tried something like this but where email NOT LIKE '%_@%.__%' but not getting the results I was hoping for.  Hoping to find an answer that I can use in a sql query as I'm trying to provide a datset for AWS quicksight.

Comment: You can try using [the regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/2501279) for that but I'm not sure you will want to =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)